# Why am I getting the run-time error "Invalid property array index"?

Tags: vb6, listbox

I have 2 list boxes and one button. Whenever the user selects items in lstAvail and presses the button, the selected items will be added to lstSelected.

The following code works fine if the loop decrements in steps of 1.

```
Private Sub Form_Load()
Dim intX As Integer

    For intX = 0 To 5
        lstAvail.AddItem "Item #" & Format$(intX, "000")
    Next

End Sub

Private Sub Command1_Click()
Dim intListX As Integer

    For intListX = lstAvail.ListCount - 1 To 0 Step -1
        If (lstAvail.Selected(intListX)) Then
            lstSelected.AddItem lstAvail.List(intListX)
            lstAvail.RemoveItem intListX
        End If
    Next

End Sub
```

But why doesn't it work when I take increment from 0 to (lstAvail.ListCount -1), as shown below? That code raises the run-time error "Invalid property array index".

```
Private Sub Command1_Click()
Dim intListX As Integer
For intListX = 0 To lstAvail.ListCount - 1
        If (lstAvail.Selected(intListX)) Then
            lstSelected.AddItem lstAvail.List(intListX)
            lstAvail.RemoveItem intListX
        End If
Next
End Sub
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Forwards Loop

The reason why this doesn't work is because you are removing items from <lstAvail>, but you are still incrementing from 0 as if the list still remains as it was.

Items in lstAvail

- "Item 000"
- "Item 001"
- "Item 002"
- "Item 003"
- "Item 004"
- "Item 005"

Let's say you select the third item in the list (ListIndex = 2), and then click the button, triggering off Command1_Click(). You will be incremented intListX until it equals 5. The following is a trace through the For loop:

---

intListX: 0

lstAvail.Selected(intListX): False

lstAvail:

- "Item 000"
- "Item 001"
- "Item 002"
- "Item 003"
- "Item 004"
- "Item 005"

---

intListX: 1

lstAvail.Selected(intListX): False

lstAvail:

- "Item 000"
- "Item 001"
- "Item 002"
- "Item 003"
- "Item 004"
- "Item 005"

---

intListX: 2

lstAvail.Selected(intListX): True

!! Remove "Item 002" !!

lstAvail:

- "Item 000"
- "Item 001"
- "Item 003"
- "Item 004"
- "Item 005"

---

intListX: 3

lstAvail.Selected(intListX): False

lstAvail:

- "Item 000"
- "Item 001"
- "Item 003"
- "Item 004"
- "Item 005"

---

intListX: 4

lstAvail.Selected(intListX): False

lstAvail:

- "Item 000"
- "Item 001"
- "Item 003"
- "Item 004"
- "Item 005"

---

intListX: 5

lstAvail.Selected(intListX): <!!Error!!>

There is no item here with index 5.

### Reversed Loop

intListX: 5

lstAvail.Selected(intListX): False

lstAvail:

- "Item 000"
- "Item 001"
- "Item 002"
- "Item 003"
- "Item 004"
- "Item 005"

---

intListX: 4

lstAvail.Selected(intListX): False

lstAvail:

- "Item 000"
- "Item 001"
- "Item 002"
- "Item 003"
- "Item 004"
- "Item 005"

---

intListX: 3

lstAvail.Selected(intListX): False

lstAvail:

- "Item 000"
- "Item 001"
- "Item 002"
- "Item 003"
- "Item 004"
- "Item 005"

---

intListX: 2

lstAvail.Selected(intListX): True

!! Remove "Item 002" !!

lstAvail:

- "Item 000"
- "Item 001"
- "Item 003"
- "Item 004"
- "Item 005"

---

intListX: 1

lstAvail.Selected(intListX): False

lstAvail:

- "Item 000"
- "Item 001"
- "Item 003"
- "Item 004"
- "Item 005"

---

intListX: 0

lstAvail.Selected(intListX): False

lstAvail:

- "Item 000"
- "Item 001"
- "Item 003"
- "Item 004"
- "Item 005"

Comment: Thank You Very Much @Mark Bertenshaw ....While debugging i observed but didn't get... Now i understood clearly...